# Pandas Seaborn Data labels showing as 0.00

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn, percentage

I have two questions:

1. My data labels are showing as 0.00 and isn't matching my cross tab. I don't know why...

Updating with the full code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('2018_ms_data_impact_only.csv', low_memory=False)
df.head()

StartDate   EndDate Status  IPAddress   Progress    duration    Finished    RecordedDate    ResponseId  RecipientLastName   ... Gender  LGBTQ   Mobile  organizing_interest Parent  Policy  policy_interest reg_to_vote unique_id   Veteran
0   4/6/18 10:32    4/6/18 10:39    1   NaN 100 391 1   4/6/18 10:39    R_1liSDxRmTKDLFfT   Mays    ... Woman   0.0 4752122624  Currently in this field 1.0 NaN NaN 0.0 0034000001VAbTAAA1  0.0
1   4/9/18 6:31 4/9/18 6:33 1   NaN 100 160 1   4/9/18 6:33 R_0ezRf2zyaLwFDa1   Mays    ... Woman   0.0 4752122684  2020    0.0 A   2020    0.0 0034000001W3tGOAAZ  0.0
2   4/9/18 9:14 4/9/18 9:15 1   NaN 100 70  1   4/9/18 9:15 R_DeHh3DQ23uQZwLD   Mays    ... Woman   0.0 4752122684  2020    0.0 A   2020    0.0 0034000001W3tGOAAZ  0.0
3   4/9/18 9:21 4/9/18 9:22 1   NaN 100 69  1   4/9/18 9:22 R_1CC0ckmyS7E1qs3   Mays    ... Woman   0.0 4752122684  2020    0.0 A   2020    0.0 0034000001W3tGOAAZ  0.0
4   4/9/18 9:28 4/9/18 9:29 1   NaN 100 54  1   4/9/18 9:29 R_01GuM5KqtHIgvEl   Mays    ... Woman   0.0 4752122684  2020    0.0 A   2020    0.0 0034000001W3tGOAAZ  0.0

def impact_action_yn_new(series):

    if series == 3:
        return 'No'
    elif series == 1:
        return 'Yes'

df['impact_action_yn_new'] = df['impact_action_yn'].apply(impact_action_yn_new)

df['impact_action_yn_new'].value_counts(sort=False)

# clean up engagement - collapse nan and 0, 2s

def engagement_new(series):
    if series == '0':
        return 'Null'
    elif series == 'NaN':
        return 'Null'
    elif series == '1':
        return '1'
    elif series == '2':
        return '2a'
    elif series == '2a':
        return '2a'
    elif series == '2b':
        return '2b'
    elif series == '3':
        return '3'
    elif series == '4':
        return '4'
    elif series == '5':
        return '5'

df['engagement_new'] = df['Engagement'].apply(engagement_new)

impact_action_table_eng = pd.crosstab(df.impact_action_yn_new,df.engagement_new)
print(impact_action_table_eng)

engagement_new          1   2a   2b    3    4    5  Null
impact_action_yn_new                                    
No                    676  508  587  683  172   31     1
Yes                   410  405  303  671  357  237     1

# Crosstab: Impact YN x Engagement - Row percentages
impact_action_table_eng_rowperc = pd.crosstab(df.impact_action_yn_new,df.engagement_new).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum()*100, axis=1)

print(impact_action_table_eng_rowperc)

engagement_new                1         2a         2b          3          4  \
impact_action_yn_new                                                          
No                    25.432656  19.112114  22.084274  25.696012   6.471031   
Yes                   17.197987  16.988255  12.709732  28.145973  14.974832   

engagement_new               5      Null  
impact_action_yn_new                      
No                    1.166290  0.037622  
Yes                   9.941275  0.041946  

#plot data 
stacked_imp_eng_rowperc = impact_action_table_eng_rowperc.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'value'})
total = float(len(df))

#set fig size
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10))

#set style
sns.set_style('whitegrid')

#plot
ax = sns.barplot(x=stacked_imp_eng_rowperc.engagement_new, 
            y=stacked_imp_eng_rowperc.value,
            hue=stacked_imp_eng_rowperc.impact_action_yn_new)

#plot legend
ax.legend(loc='center right',bbox_to_anchor=(.95,.9),ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True)

#plot axis labels
for p in ax.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    ax.text(p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2.,
            height,
            '{:1.2f}'.format(height/total),
            ha="center")
ax.set(xlabel='Engagement Level', ylabel='% Reporting an Action within Last 12 Months');
```

I'm not sure why the data labels on the bar plot are showing as 0.00. It is calling the crosstab. Any thoughts?

2. Is there a way to convert the crosstab calcualtions to show as a percentage? I'd like to plot those percentages instead of decimals.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: What is df? Please provide a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: df = my dataframe.

    df = pd.read_csv('2018_ms_data_impact_only.csv', low_memory=False)

Comment: This is very difficult to reproduce. Providing a [mcve] (also see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) would allow people to run the code and possibly find a solution for you.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest updated above